# Email setup for digitalocean server

Tags: wordpress, email, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, php-7

I am using digital ocean server with Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP7. I am having wordpress site. But mail functionality doesn't work. I have tried some tutorials but no success. Can someone suggest how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you've tried but you can install postfix and make a relay to your mail provider and send your mails over your own mailbox. Then you have now worries about spam and all the mechanism you need to prevend your emails from the spam folder.

https://blog.bartlweb.net/2011/02/smtp-relay-host-mit-authentifizierung-in-postfix-konfigurieren/

Otherwise if you install postfix without an relay then you have to permit your network. But then it's possible that your emails are rated as spam.